# If $\dim \ker(T-3i I)=3$, determine all possibilities for the Jordan canonical form of $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $8$-dimensional complex vector space, $T: V \to V$ an operator, and let the minimal polynomial of $T$ be equal to $(x-3i)^4$. If $\dim \ker(T-3i I)=3$, determine all possibilities for the Jordan canonical form of $T$.

The invariant factors are $(x-3i)^4,(x-3i),(x-3i),(x-3i),(x-3i)$, since $\dim V = 8$, $T$ has minimal polynomial $(x-3i)^4$, and $\dim \ker(T-3i I)=3$ implies that three of the invariant factors are $(x-3i)$.

Thus the possible Jordan canonical form is $$J_4(3i) \oplus J_1(3i) \oplus J_1(3i) \oplus J_1(3i) \oplus J_1(3i) = \begin{pmatrix} 3i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 3i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 3i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3i \end{pmatrix}$$

Is this correct? I want to make sure I understand how to do this, my professor seems to like this type of problem

Comment: I´m confused, this Jordan form looks like $\text{dim  ker} (T-3iI)=4$??

Comment: @PeterMelech I was confused too lol. I don't know why I made all my invariant factors linear when $(x-3i)$ divides any power of $(x-3i)$. Thanks for the answer

Comment: and I can´t count, this would have been $\text{dim}=5$ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be three Jordan blocks, because there is an eigenvector for each block, so You have $J_4(3i)\oplus J_3(3i)\oplus J_1(3i)$ or $J_4(3i)\oplus J_2(3i)\oplus J_2(3i)$ and of course You can permute the blocks.